VS Code + pytest - How to move the whole project to a subdirectory?
I have an existing Python project which looks like this:
.venv/
    ...
example_package/
    __init__.py
tests/
    test_example_package.py

Imagine that I worked on this project for a while and then decided to add a frontend to some kind of web service using React.
I created a new directory called React, and a new directory called Python to organize my code.
The project structure now looks like this:
Python/
    .venv/
        ...
    example_package/
        __init__.py
    tests/
       test_example_package.py
React/
    ...

But there is a problem. My tests no longer work. So I ran the VS Code "configure tests" command and set the subdirectory where the tests are to be found to Python. But this did not fix the whole issue, and the pytest discovery process fails with the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example_package'

It seems relatively obvious as to what is happening. pytest is being run by VS Code, with a current working directory set to . instead of ./Python/.
How can I fix this?

At this point, your project file is already at the same level as the vscode workspace, and the Settings in the workspace will not take effect for the parent folder. I recommend that you select a new workspace.

Your project file is already at the same level as the vscode workspace, and the Settings in the workspace will not take effect for the parent folder. I recommend that you select a new workspace.
The new directory structure is more like:
workspace/
    .vscode/
        settings.json
    Python/
        .venv/
            ...
        example_package/
            __init__.py
        tests/
           test_example_package.py
    React/
        ...


I'm not sure I fully understand this. "project file" = .vscode/settings.json ? Which new workspace should I be selecting? That directory structure you have included at the end looks very similar if not identical to my own.

VSCode workspace settings are determined by settings.json in the .vscode folder, and by default the workspace folder is also used as the root directory. Your current directorys are the peer directories, it is very troublesome when trying to import. You can use the parent folder of the Python and React folders as a workspace.
